# UIWebView getting other domain url

Tags: ios, uiwebview, request

My app has `UIWebView` and so far it was working fine. All of a sudden, I am getting some other domain url after each request.

**Earlier : abc.com/

Now :

First url : abc.com/

Second url : abc://**

I have no idea why I am getting this url all of a sudden.

Comment: second one is call back URL , i think you get this is safari correct

Comment: @Abu.Karthik : Where is the callback url set ?

Comment: it defaultly taken in ios , if you need call in plist at the key name of URL Schema

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I mean to say, why and from where, the url of this domain is being created ?